# MVC Project cross talk

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Eclipse Juno with Spring STS 3.1.0. I have 2 mvc projects in the same workspace. One of the projects can send and receive jms messages. It uses a Spring JmsMessagListener bean to receive messages. The bean maps to a listener class with an onMessage method. When I run the project withoug jms in on the VMWare tc server, I get the following message in the console every 5 seconds:

WARN : org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'mht.alert.queue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The project seems to be attempting to connect to my activemq broker which is not running since I am not running the project with jms built in. I don't understand why this should happen. I have included the web.xml files for the two projects. Hopefully someone can give me a clue as to why this is happening. It's not a showstopper as I can ignore the messages or bring up the broker to silence them, however it would be best to deal with it properly.

Thanks in advance

Here is the web.xml file for the project that does not have jms:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
   /javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listenerclass>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the web.xml file for the project with jms built in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, 
                 /WEB-INF/spring/jms-config.xml, 
                 /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml,
                 /WEB-INF/spring/datasource-tx.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>    

<!--<start id="filter_security" /> -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<!--<end id="filter_security" />-->

<!--<start id="filter_mapping_security" /> -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!--<end id="filter_mapping_security" />-->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- This servlet is mapped to all requests at the root level -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the contents of my root-context.xml, not that spring-security.xml is commented out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <!-- Import the datasource-tx.xml file to configure the StudentDao service and make
     it visible to the entire application
  -->
<import resource="classpath:datasource-tx.xml" />
<!-- <import resource="spring-security.xml" /> -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml` does not have the JMS config? Please post the contents of that.

Comment: I double checked, it was in there but is commented out